# React JS Change text value and submit

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

Facing this Error : Failed propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`. Check the render method of `BasicInputBox`.

I am returning Following Component :

```
<BasicInputBox label="Student Name :" valChange={this.nameChange} value={datafield.name}/>
```

and the component :

```
var BasicInputBox = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    return <div>
        <tr>
        <td><label> { this.props.label } </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" onChange={ this.props.valChange } value={ this.props.value } /></td>
      </tr>
    </div>
    }
});
```

Value is not changing while changing in text field.
And the following is the function of `nameChange` function

Comment: nameChange: function(event){
                        this.setState({name: event.target.value})
                      },

Comment: And can we assume that `value` will be correctly updated by a render call, and that `nameChange` will be changing a state somewhere that will cause a re-render? It would be helpful to see that code.

Comment: `tr` is not a legal child of `div`. Please show more code and make sure this is clean and working (up to the point where you're having trouble).

Comment: [See spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element): Contexts in which this element can be used. `tr` elements can't appear just anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to work fine, assuming the parts you have not shared are working correctly.

If you're having trouble, it is likely in the listener or in the render of the parent component. Here is a working example with your element (note: I have modified structure slightly to ensure legal html):

```
var BasicInputBox = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    return <div>
        <label> { this.props.label } </label>
        <input type="text" onChange={ this.props.valChange } value={ this.props.value } />
    </div>
    }
});
var Wrapper = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      datafield: {
        name: ''
      }      
    }
  },
  nameChange: function(e) {

    this.setState({datafield: {name: e.currentTarget.value}})

  },
  render: function() {
    let datafield = this.state.datafield
    return <BasicInputBox label="Student Name :" valChange={this.nameChange} value={datafield.name}/>
  }
})
```

Working snippet (ugly after babel/jsx translation).

```js
"use strict";

var BasicInputBox = React.createClass({
  displayName: "BasicInputBox",

  render: function render() {
    return React.createElement(
      "div",
      null,
      React.createElement(
        "tr",
        null,
        React.createElement(
          "td",
          null,
          React.createElement(
            "label",
            null,
            " ",
            this.props.label,
            " "
          )
        ),
        React.createElement(
          "td",
          null,
          React.createElement("input", { type: "text", onChange: this.props.valChange, value: this.props.value })
        )
      )
    );
  }
});
var Wrapper = React.createClass({
  displayName: "Wrapper",

  getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
    return {
      datafield: {
        name: ''
      }
    };
  },
  nameChange: function nameChange(e) {
    this.setState({ datafield: { name: e.currentTarget.value } });
  },
  render: function render() {
    var datafield = this.state.datafield;
    return React.createElement(BasicInputBox, { label: "Student Name :", valChange: this.nameChange, value: datafield.name });
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Wrapper, null), document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```